# forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type" for image and data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, post, content-type, nsurlrequest

I want to send user picture and user's other information to server using POST method from my iphone application.

my content type is as below

```
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"--"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
```

but it is posting only image. my other data is not posting on server.

And if I use below content type then

```
[ request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

then it is sending other data only. not sending image.

Please suggest me way by which I can send both image and other info.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) its simple and easy to use :)

Comment: Why? It's no longer active development http://allseeing-i.com/[request_release]. Just linking to some framework when someone asks someone about implementation details isn't a good answer.

Comment: its no longer active development but it is still working smooth, and i am giving him an alternative, because even after 45 min no one responded to his question

Comment: But referring him to a framework still isn't an answer to his question.

Comment: Too bad this got the question mark, it's not an answer indeed. @ViratNaithani would you care to enhance your answer for future readers (e.g. with how ASIHTTPRequest solves this)?

Answer (score 0):

Encode the image using Base64 like this

```
[Base64Coder encodeData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
```

You can download Base64 class from [this link](http://imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php).

**Edited**: Added Code sample

```
NSString *reqStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"iPhone_request=<game><name>%@</name><image>%@</image></game>",txtGameName.text, [Base64Coder encodeData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgGame.image)]];

// Replace occurrences of + with %2B
reqStr = [[reqStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
reqData = [reqStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:reqData];
```